# How to update the XML file

Tags: php, xml

I am using XML to save the config data and access them later. Im doing it with `fwrite`
which essentially rewrites the entire file. is it possible to update only the tags that i want? Thanks.

EDIT:
This is my XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<API>
    <clientID>347858725837465247835</clientID>
    <apiKey>2347857893465872345</apiKey>
</API>
```

Comment: I think you will need to post up either your XML or your PHP, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PHP SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) library for such a manipulation:

```
$info = simplexml_load_file('fileName.xml');

// update
$info->clientID[0] = "1234"; // new value

// save the updated document
$info->asXML('fileName.xml');
```

Comment: well it works but look how it saving the xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<API>
 <clientID>5634uyfh76hd3d4r</clientID>
 <apiKey>keyhere</apiKey>
<API><clientID>123</clientID><apiKey>1223</apiKey></API></API>
it pastes the tags again

Comment: Update line may need index: `$info->API->clientID[0] = "5454"`

Comment: @OscarM. still does the same

Comment: Tested locally, update line should be `$info->clientID[0] = "5454";`. Since API is your root node.

Comment: @MeletisFlevarakis You mean "now".

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml path with php

This an example

```
$root = simplexml_load_file("xml file url"); // url of xml file
$client = $root->xpath("/API[ClientID='23242342342']"); // look for specific tag
$client[0]->clientID="64564575"; // modify specific tag             
$root->asXml("xml file url"); // save changes
```

Comment: I don't see `stock` and `product` nodes in the OP's posted XML.

Comment: i wrote the previous answer before he give us the xml structure , and my answer is edited

Comment: You answered 6 minutes ago and the XML was provided.

Comment: i didn't see it . i guess if we talk about the edited answer ?