# Update data in XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Actually I am working on a website for which I manage the database using XML file(s). I want to update the XML file which means I want to change the text in between tags of XML file. For example my XML file structure is as follows

```
<books>
<book>
<Name>BookName1</Name>
<Author>author1</Author>
</book>
<book>
<Name>BookName2</Name>
<Author>author2</Author>
</book>
</books>
```

Now what I want to do is update the `BookName1` in the Name tag to `BookName2`. Any tag at any node likewise. I want to do it with `PHP`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609422/how-to-update-the-xml-file)

Comment: minimal research effort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file/4906459#4906459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). You can access and change your elements like an array then:

```
<?php 
$string = '<books>
<book>
<Name>BookName1</Name>
<Author>author1</Author>
</book>
<book>
<Name>BookName2</Name>
<Author>author2</Author>
</book>
</books>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$xml->book[0]->Name= "Something else"; // or BookName2
echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```